# Why browser does so weird moves line?

Tags: html, css

[image: Realy]

I heed this: [image: I need this]

```css
.table{
    width: 500px;
}
.table td{
    vertical-align: middle:
}
.logo{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="logo">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8odfqCs.png" alt="" />
            </span>
            <span>Ололо лололо олололо лололо лолололо лололлололл лолололлл оллолло лоллогллол лололо</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why is the first line posted normally, and the other at the bottom?
I tried different "display", "float" and "clear" attributes but nothing happened

Comment: Because the image increases the line height. Where would you want your text to be?

Comment: @Siguza yes, also because `display: inline` + `vertical-align: middle` are used. @MixerOID these two lines displays OK, but first has large height.

Comment: @Siguza like this http://i.imgur.com/euTOp2e.png

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Using `display: table-cell` you can get your desired result. May not work in all browsers though.

```css
.table{
    width: 500px;
}
.table td{
    vertical-align: middle:
}
.table td span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="logo">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8odfqCs.png" alt="" />
            </span>
            
            <span>Ололо лололо олололо лололо лолололо лололлололл лолололлл оллолло лоллогллол лололо</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to do this alignment using css

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1nzumjI.png Text to wrap around the image below if a lot of text example: http://i.imgur.com/hUFVNYl.png Table - is not the solution